# Magento2.4.2 Too many password reset requests

Tags: admin, security, magento2.4.2, password-recovery, forgot-password

About to migrate. I get this issue for Admins. I need to disable this so my team (18 people) can choose their own passwords.
Can I disable this ? If only for an hour or so.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the admin panel, go to `Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Security -> Max Number of Password Reset Requests` = 0.

You might also check "Min Time Between Password Reset Requests", "Maximum Login Failures to Lockout Account" and "Lockout Time (minutes)" depending on the situation.

If you do not have access to the admin panel, just use the CLI like this:

```
bin/magento config:set admin/security/max_number_password_reset_requests 0
```

Or, change the value directly in the DB, core_config_data table.

If any user has been lock, you can unlock them from CLI:

```
bin/magento admin:user:unlock username
```